# How to reposition electron app using pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I got this code working with calculator.exe but I can't get it to work with vscode app.
I'm trying to open a vscode workspace.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start(r"C:\vscode\Code.exe C:\Documents\my.workspace")
dlg_spec = app.window()
dlg_spec.move_window(x=0, y=0, width=1000, height=1000, repaint=True)
```

And I get this error

```
(electron) Sending uncompressed crash reports is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Electron. Set { compress: true } to opt-in to the new behavior. Crash reports will be uploaded gzipped, which most crash reporting servers support.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 250, in __resolve_control
    ctrl = wait_until_passes(
  File "C:\Users\me\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\script.py", line 4, in <module>
    dlg_spec.move_window(x=0, y=0, width=1000, height=1000, repaint=True)
  File "C:\Users\me\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 396, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Users\me\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Users\me\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 203, in __get_ctrl
    dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**criteria[0]))
  File "C:\Users\me\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'backend': 'win32', 'process': 13116}
```